# Java compiler CorruptedCacheException : CorruptedCacheException

Tags: android

I just dowloaded Android Studio on my macbook pro (OS Sierra). To test the configuration I started to make a simple app, with empty Activity.
However right from the start I cannot go any further because of the following error:

`Caused by: org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted IndexBlock 31322 found in cache '/private/var/root/.gradle/caches/journal-1/file-access.bin'.`

I tried to download a new JDK that I used inside my project structure instead of the embedded JDK.

It is worth noticing that when I go to the SDK manager the API android 9.+(Q) status is partially installed.

So what can I do to compile this simple project ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to do following steps:

1. Open your /Users/macuser/ folder
2. Press CMD + SHIFT + . (dot/period) to view hidden folders
3. DELETE .gradle folder
4. Restart Android Studio

Comment: If you find helpful answer,please accept and close the question.